# Try to read a dropdown list but get an error e.options is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

How can read a selected Optionfield? I get `TypeError` for the following code.

Here is my HTML text:

```html
<label for="raum" id="raum">Raum</label>
                                <select name="raum" id="raum">
                                    <option value="wohnzimmer">wohnzimmer</option>
                                    <option value="Küche">Küche</option>
                                    <option value="schlafzimmer">schlalfzimmer</option>
                                </select>
```

I use the eventListener to start a function:

```js
document.getElementById("eintragen").addEventListener("click", eintragen);

function eintragen(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  laufendeNummer();
}

function laufendeNummer() {
  var e = document.getElementById('raum');
  var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  console.log(value);
}
```

but I always get following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.options is undefined

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.:

- You are using and id twice (`id="raum"`) which is not allowed in HTML, ids have to be unique.
- You are adding the listener to the incorrect element (`eintragen` doesn't even exist in the code you have provided).

If you fix that, your code should work:

```js
document.getElementById("raum").addEventListener("click", raum);

function raum(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  laufendeNummer();
}

function laufendeNummer() {
  var e = document.getElementById('raum');
  var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<label for="raum">Raum</label>
<select name="raum" id="raum">
  <option value="wohnzimmer">wohnzimmer</option>
  <option value="Küche">Küche</option>
  <option value="schlafzimmer">schlalfzimmer</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh men thank you. now all is fine. i see all the code but did not see this small error :-)